# Python deal with HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A python beginner get tortured here, need some help:-(

```
def getLinkinfo(endpoint):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint)
    link_info = response.read().decode()
    return link_info

text=getLinkinfo('http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/month-jan-001.html')
soup1=BeautifulSoup(text,'html.parser')
k=soup1.find_all('div','class'=='article')
```

Here I have already cut the main body I need to deal with, and one of the outputs is as shown below:

```
<div class="article"><h5>1. <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2020/jan/01/lets-resolve-to-reconnect-says-welby-in-new-year-message" target="_blank">Let's resolve to reconnect, says Welby in new year message</a></h5>
<p class="metadata">Wed 1 Jan 2020 00:01 GMT</p>
<p class="metadata">Category: <span>UK-News</span></p>
<p class="snippet">The archbishop of Canterbury will urge people to make personal connections with others in 2020 to create a new unity in a divided society. In his new …</p></div>
```

Here my question is how can i get: 
(1)'Title' between <h5>,<a> tag 
(2) 'Category' which is behind <p class="metadata">(Here are two <p class="metadata">s, one with time is not needed) 
(3)'Snippet' which is behind <p class="snippet"> 
Thx for help in advance, I feel if I know how to deal with this example, I can process a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint as pp


def main(url):
    r = urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    goal = [(x.a.text, x.select("p")[1].text.split(' ', 1)[1], x.select_one('p.snippet').text)
            for x in soup.select('.article')]
    pp(goal)


main('http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/month-jan-001.html')
```

Output:

```
[("Let's resolve to reconnect, says Welby in new year message",
  'UK-News',
  'The archbishop of Canterbury will urge people to make personal connections '
  'with others in 2020 to create a new unity in a divided society. In his new '
  '…'),
 ("Be honest. You're not going to read all those books on your holiday, are "
  'you?',
  'Books',
  'Every year, about this time, my Instagram feed fills up with pictures of '
  'books. They’re piled somewhere between five and ten inches high, sometimes '
  'st …'),
 ("Mariah Carey's Twitter account hacked on New Year's Eve",
  'Music',
  'Mariah Carey’s Twitter account appeared to have been hacked late Tuesday '
  'afternoon, sharing numerous racist slurs and comments with the singer’s '
  '21.4 …'),
 ('The joy audit: how to have more fun in 2020',
  'Life-and-Style',
  'The last time I felt joy was at an event that would be many people’s vision '
  'of hell: a drunken Taylor Swift club-night singalong in the early hours of '
  '…'),
 ('Providence Lost by Paul Lay review – the rise and fall of Oliver Cromwell’s '
  'Protectorate',
  'Books',
  'The only public execution of a British head of state occurred 371 years ago '
  'outside the Banqueting House in Whitehall on 30 January 1649. It was a rad '
  '…'),
 ('Zero-carbon electricity outstrips fossil fuels in Britain across 2019',
  'Business',
  'Summary: Zero-carbon energy became Britain’s largest electricity source in '
  '2019, delivering nearly half the country’s electrical power and for the '
  'first time o …'),
 ('The final sprint: will any of the Democratic candidates excite voters?',
  'US-News',
  'Democrats overwhelmingly agree that their top priority in 2020 is to remove '
  'Donald Trump from office. But which of the many Democrats running for pres '
  '…'),
 ('War epics, airmen and young Sopranos: essential films for 2020',
  'Film',
  '1917 An epic of Lean-ian proportions is delivered in this spectacular from '
  'director and co-writer Sam Mendes, who has developed a real-life story of h '
  '…'),
 ("Stashing your cash: the beginner's guide to saving",
  'Life-and-Style',
  'Much like going for a run or eating your greens, saving your cash offers '
  'long-term benefits, but is not always appealing. And, let’s face it, there '
  'ar …'),
 ("'I'm on the hunt for humour and hope': what will authors be reading in "
  '2020?',
  'Books',
  'Matt Haig I have been very dark and gloomy with my reading habits this '
  'year, perhaps in tune with the social mood. Like a pig sniffing for '
  'truffles, I …'),
 ('Twenty athletes set to light up the Tokyo 2020 Olympics',
  'Sport',
  'Dina Asher-Smith Great Britain Athletics, 100m, 200m, 4x100m Seb Coe, who '
  'knows a thing or two about winning Olympic titles, believes Asher-Smith '
  'will …'),
 ('The most exciting movies of 2020 – horror',
  'Film',
  'The Grudge A belated English language reboot of Japanese classic Ju-On: The '
  'Grudge (2002), this stars Andrea Riseborough and Demián Bichir as detectiv '
  '…'),
 ('Diary of a Murderer by Kim Young-ha review – dark stories from South Korea',
  'Books',
  'Given that loss of memory has become a familiar device in fiction, and the '
  'psychopath such a popular character archetype, we shouldn’t be too surprise '
  '…'),
 ('US election, Brexit and China to sway the markets in 2020',
  'Business',
  'After profiting from strong markets in 2019, investors are expecting 2020 '
  'to bring further rising asset prices and lively merger activity. But '
  'Brexit, …'),
 ('TS Eliot’s intimate letters to confidante unveiled after 60 years',
  'Books',
  'A collection of more than 1,000 letters from the Nobel laureate TS Eliot to '
  'his confidante and muse Emily Hale is unveiled this week, after having bee '
  '…'),
 ('Clive Lewis calls for unity among Labour leadership hopefuls',
  'Politics',
  'Summary: The Labour leadership hopeful Clive Lewis has called for unity '
  'among would-be candidates to succeed Jeremy Corbyn as they confront the '
  '“cliff face” of …'),
 ("Visa applications: Home Office refuses to reveal 'high risk' countries",
  'UK-News',
  'Summary: Campaign groups have criticised the Home Office after it refused '
  'to release details of which countries are deemed a “risk” in an algorithm '
  'that filter …'),
 ('Victims of NYE Surrey road crash were BA cabin crew',
  'UK-News',
  'At least seven people have been killed across the UK in road traffic '
  'collisions over the new year period. The deaths included three British '
  'Airways ca …'),
 ('Man held on suspicion of double murder after bodies found in house',
  'UK-News',
  'Police have arrested a man on suspicion of murdering two people at a house '
  'in the village of Duffield in Derbyshire. The murder investigation was laun '
  '…'),
 ("Great expectations: 'The quest for perfection has cannibalised my identity'",
  'Life-and-Style',
  '“You need to practice self-compassion,” my psychologist says to me. This is '
  'our sixth session and as per usual he is struggling to find a phrase, a po '
  '…'),
 ('Anti-Islamic slogans spray-painted near mosque in Brixton',
  'UK-News',
  'Anti-Islamic slogans have been painted on a building close to a mosque and '
  'cultural centre in south London, the Metropolitan police have said. Officer '
  '…'),
 ('Michael van Gerwen 3-7 Peter Wright: PDC world darts championship final – '
  'as it happened',
  'Sport',
  'Summary: That’s it for tonight’s blog, so I’ll leave you with a report from '
  'Ally Pally. Thanks for your company, goodnight! There’s so much affection '
  'for Peter …'),
 ('Greggs launches meatless steak bake to beef up its vegan range',
  'Business',
  'Greggs, the UK’s largest bakery chain, will end speculation about its hotly '
  'anticipated new vegan snack by launching a meat-free version of its popula '
  '…'),
 ('Woodford folk festival review – a much-needed moment of positivity and '
  'reprieve',
  'Music',
  'If Woodford folk festival was in mourning this year, you wouldn’t have '
  'known it. The death in May of festival elder and decade-long patron Bob '
  'Hawke c …'),
 ('Household haze: how to reduce smoke in your home without an air purifier',
  'Life-and-Style',
  'Summary: On 1 January, Canberra experienced its worst air quality on '
  'record. Smoke from Australia’s devastating bushfires has now blown as far '
  'as Queenstown, N …'),
 ("Sadiq Khan pledges free London travel for disabled people's carers",
  'Politics',
  'Sadiq Khan has kickstarted his bid for a second term as London mayor by '
  'pledging free travel on the city’s transport for anyone accompanying a '
  'disable …'),
 ('‘Everyone thought I was mad’: how to make a life-changing decision – and '
  'stick to it',
  'Life-and-Style',
  'Summary: When I was 26, I broke up with a long-term partner, got an '
  'ill-advised facial piercing and changed careers – all in the space of a '
  'month. What I learn …'),
 ('In the Line of Duty review – race-against-time cop thriller',
  'Film',
  'There’s a straight-to-video feel to this cop thriller, directed by action '
  'veteran Steven C Miller, written by Jeremy Drysdale (who scripted the indie '
  '…'),
 ("Manchester poet Tony Walsh performs tribute to children's hospital",
  'UK-News',
  'The performance poet Tony Walsh, whose ode to Manchester became a worldwide '
  'hit after the Arena bomb, has written a moving tribute to Royal Manchester '
  '…'),
 ('Can your phone keep you fit? Our writers try 10 big fitness apps – from '
  'weightlifting to pilates',
  'Life-and-Style',
  'Centr Price £15.49 a month. What is it? A full-service experience from the '
  'Hollywood star Chris Hemsworth: not just workouts, but a complete meal plan '
  '…'),
 ('We Are from Jazz review – zany Russian musical comedy',
  'Film',
  'Only in a Woody Allen film will you hear quite as much Dixieland jazz as '
  'this. Here is We Are from Jazz, or We Are Jazzmen, the zany jazz comedy '
  'music …'),
 ('The Other Half of Augusta Hope by Joanna Glen review – high emotions',
  'Books',
  'Summary: Who is Augusta Hope’s “other half”? In Glen’s debut, shortlisted '
  'for the Costa first novel prize, at first it’s Augusta’s twin sister, '
  'although the di …'),
 ('Tara Erraught/James Baillieu review – quietly intense and simply exquisite',
  'Music',
  'Irish mezzo Tara Erraught’s latest Wigmore recital with her pianist James '
  'Baillieu took place between Christmas and New Year, though her beautifully '
  'c …'),
 ('Talking Horses: picking the five best races of the last decade',
  'Sport',
  'You might take the view that the end of the decade is actually a year away, '
  'but at least it’s 10 years since I last did something like this. I’ve limi '
  '…'),
 ('The Reality Bubble by Ziya Tong review – blind spots and hidden truths',
  'Books',
  'Publishing functions very much like the fashion world. Like a suddenly '
  'ubiquitous cut of hem or style of trainer, a book comes along every few '
  'seasons …'),
 ('Alleged drink-driver arrested on motorway had no front tyres',
  'UK-News',
  'An alleged drink-driver who was arrested on the motorway on New Year’s Day '
  'had been driving without front tyres. The motorist was said to be nearly si '
  '…'),
 ('MC Beaton, multimillion-selling author of Agatha Raisin novels, dies aged '
  '83',
  'Books',
  'MC Beaton, the prolific creator of the much loved fictional detectives '
  'Agatha Raisin and Hamish Macbeth, has died after a short illness at the age '
  'of …'),
 ("First transgender Marvel superhero coming 'very soon'",
  'Film',
  'The first transgender character in a Marvel movie will probably appear in a '
  'film released next year. Speaking at an event at the New York Film Academy '
  '…'),
 ('The six-pack can wait: how to set fitness goals you will actually keep',
  'Life-and-Style',
  'Summary: Most of us have, at some point in our lives, looked in the mirror '
  'and decided we need a radical image overhaul – especially in January. Then, '
  'when we …'),
 ('Gold from Highlands mine to be made into Scottish jewellery',
  'UK-News',
  'A small goldmine in the Highlands plans to start producing gold in '
  'commercial quantities for the first time after repeated delays. The mine at '
  'Cononis …'),
 ('Tell us about your mixed-sex civil partnership plans',
  'UK-News',
  'The first mixed-sex couples have started to become civil partners in the '
  'UK, following a landmark legal battle won by Rebecca Steinfeld and Charles '
  'Ke …'),
 ('England ready for tortoise and hare race in second Test at Newlands',
  'Sport',
  'As Harold Macmillan is supposed to have explained, there are times when the '
  'best‑laid plans disappear like melting snow in springtime and a whole new '
  '…'),
 ("All Federico Fellini's films – ranked!",
  'Film',
  '20. The Voice of the Moon (1990) A gentle, episodic Fellini, with Roberto '
  'Benigni playing Ivo, a madcap character who travels far and wide across the '
  '…'),
 ('Isle of Wight’s rattling, rolling, charming ex-tube trains face end of the '
  'line',
  'UK-News',
  'The train trip from Ryde Pier Head to Shanklin on the Isle of Wight in '
  'carriages built 80 years ago for the small tunnels of certain London '
  'Undergroun …'),
 ('Meaty by Samantha Irby review – scatological essays',
  'Books',
  'To call Samantha Irby’s book scatological would be an understatement. This '
  'is a book about assholes – yes, the kind who cheats on you, or never calls, '
  '…'),
 ("Call for more diverse Lake District sparks row over area's future",
  'UK-News',
  'The head of the Lake District national park authority (LDNPA) has been '
  'accused of using the issue of diversity to push through commercial '
  'development …'),
 ("Sharon Choi: how we fell for Bong Joon-ho's translator",
  'Film',
  'Just when you thought Bong Joon-ho – the affable maestro of Korean cinema '
  'and now, with his class-conscious Cannes winner Parasite, champion of the '
  'pe …'),
 ('Whitehall reforms may lead to discrimination, says union',
  'Politics',
  'Boris Johnson’s “seismic” Whitehall reforms, including regular exams for '
  'senior civil servants, could lead to discrimination against staff on the '
  'grou …'),
 ('The most exciting movies of 2020 – biopics',
  'Film',
  'Respect Having wiped away her Catstoddler snot, Jennifer Hudson gives her '
  'pipes a wider airing in this Aretha Franklin biopic which – unlike other '
  'mov …'),
 ('Tune-free pop and the new Katie Hopkins: our 2020 celebrity predictions',
  'Life-and-Style',
  'There are two ways to spend New Year’s Eve, as best as I can tell: you '
  'either dirty the floor of a house party and spend the smallest of the small '
  'hou …')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Great question. Covers the basic common issues of finding selective text that many come across.
We can use `find` command of `BeautifulSoup` itself to get selective text as below:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/month-jan-001.html'
html = requests.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# 1. To get PARENT TEXT only and ignore CHILD TEXT
title = soup.find('h5')
titletextonly = soup.find_all(text=True, recursive=False) # will give only parent text
#fulltitletext = soup.find_all(text=True, recursive=True) # will give all text under it including child text

titletext = "".join(titletextonly)
##################################################

# 2. Category
p_elements = soup.find_all('p',class_='metadata')
for p_element in p_elements:
    p_with_span_element = p_element.find('span')
    span_text = p_with_span_element.text # UK-News
##################################################

# 3. Snippet
p_snippet_text = soup.find('p', class_='snipppet').text
```